# Issue while presenting New View controller having Transparent Background with Transition from Left to right

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, catransition

I am trying to present a new view controller from Left Side with Transition. Here is the Code.

```
 @IBAction func presentNewVC(_ sender: Any) {

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let leftMenuController:NewViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as! NewViewController

        leftMenuController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

        leftMenuController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        leftMenuController.definesPresentationContext = false

        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 1.0
        transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft

        transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved

        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        present(leftMenuController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

Now while sliding Animation is being performed while transition the existing view in background also appears to be sliding.

**Ideally the transparent new view controller should appear to move from left to right but it also shows existing view as it's background while moving.**

**Edit: Just to bring more clarity:** 
It's not How to Navigate from Left to Right I am looking for. The Transition is achieved & working fine. The Issue is different. As my Left Menu View is transparent, while presenting it from left to right it also shows underlying existing view as it's own background while transition. 
Please refer the screenshots & Video. Just want to stop this while transition. Only left transparent view being presented should move from left to right.
Please refer Video & Screenshot for more details.

[Click here to watch video to understand the issue](https://vimeo.com/200627343)

While Animation: (Problem)[image]

At the End: (As expected) [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I've been using for left to right transition, is this what you are looking for?

```
class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform()
{
    let src = self.source
    let dst = self.destination

    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                    src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Tried to apply your solution. It crashes.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The specified modal presentation style doesn't have a corresponding presentation controller.'